# Have a date in vb.net surrounded by # signs what do they do?

Tags: .net, vb.net, date, datetime, syntax

Usually when comparing a date that is hard coded I would use a string, but my query brings back #1/1/0001 12:00:00 AM# if a date hasn't been set in the AS 400 database. I tired just comparing "1/1/0001 12:00:00 AM" because I though that was the other would error but it seems to work find in a comparison to another date time. 
What do the # mean in this instance.

```
If lastChg <> #1/1/0001 12:00:00 AM# Then 

''do stuff

End If
```

Comment: It is called a *date literal*  it converts the TEXT to an actual DateTime type.  `Usually when comparing a date that is hard coded I would use a string`  dates are not strings, and strings are not dates

Comment: More specifically, this is the date literal for `Date.MinValue`, which you could use in this case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`lastChg` is probably declared as `Date` or `DateTime`. `Date` is just a VB alias for `System.DateTime`. You cannot compare a `Date` value with a `String`, but you can compare a `Date` constant with a `Date` variable. `#1/1/0001 12:00:00 AM#` is a so-called date literal and is of type `Date`. It is a textual representation of a date constant in VB code.

You could write

```
Const EmptyDate AS Date = #1/1/0001 12:00:00 AM#

If lastChg <> EmptyDate Then 
    ''do stuff
End If
```

In any case make sure that if `lastChg` is of type `Date` you compare it to a date literal (with `#`), but if it is a `String` to a string literal (with `"`).

---

If you have `Option Strict Off`, then you can also write something like

```vb
Dim d As Date
d = "1/1/0001 12:00:00 AM"
```

Here VB will Parse the date string and convert it to a `Date` automatically. While `d = #1/1/0001 12:00:00 AM#` will not convert anything, since the date literal is already of type `Date`.

This can possibly fail on an another computer using a different culture. Will `"1/2/2023"` be converted to a 1st February or to a 2nd of January? It may even throw an exception of other separators are expected, like `"1.2.2023"`.

Prefer the year-first format `yyyy-MM-dd` to avoid confusion: `#2023-05-04#`.

Comment: lastChg <> "1/1/0001 12:00:00 AM" runs the same aslastChg <> #1/1/0001 12:00:00 AM# which is why I was confused

Comment: If you have `Option Strict On` (and you should have it!) then you get the error: *Option Strict On disallows implicit conversions from 'String' to 'Date'*. The problem with these automatic conversions is that they might hide coding errors.

Comment: I see, I don't think I have every turned that one before I have just always used strings :/ thanks

Comment: Dates are especially tricky, because their string representation depends on the current locales. What works on one PC could fail on another. This makes automatic (and possibly unintended) date conversion dangerous.

Answer (score 1):

Most languages require you to use strings for date literals, and then the compiler will parse the string into a date object (at compile time, of course... it's never a string in memory). VB actually has special syntax for date literals.

Most of the time the special syntax doesn't matter, as shown by other languages where the compiler will generally know what you mean for string vs date. This sample is fine converted to any strongly-typed language that uses string-ish date literals, because the compiler will see the DateTime variable and know how to encode the literal:

```
If "2017-07-25" <> MyDateTimeVariable Then ...
```

But there are some situations where VB's syntax is nice. One of these is dynamic objects. Say you have a method that returns a `dynamic` (COM does this, or some unmanaged libraries will force this on you). In another language, you might have code roughly equivalent to this:

```
If "2017-07-25" = MyDynamicMethodThatIKnowReturnsADate() Then '...
```

Using string notation for date literals, the compiler is probably gonna just use a string literal here. You'd be forced to cast the method result or construct a DateTime object to get good code. But now look at this:

```
If #2017-07-25# = MyDynamicMethodThatIKnowReturnsADate() Then '...
```

Now the compiler will definitely give you a DateTime object for that literal, and since you know the dynamic method is really gonna give you a DateTime the comparison will just work as expected. Boom.

Another example is database results, which often come back from ADO.Net just typed as `Object`. Having a real DateTime literal there allows the runtime to know what to do when comparing with the database column.

Comment: VB does not allow a string in constant declarations of dates, even with Option Strict Off, because the conversion is done at runtime. A date literal however is converted at compile time.

Comment: Yes, I know. It seems the OP comes from a platform that is used to the string-ish notation, and I'm trying to explain why VB's syntax is desirable. I have an edit that might help make this clearer.

Answer (score 0):

It's like " for string but [# is for date](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.aspx#instantiating_datetime).

```
Dim date1 As Date = #5/1/2008 8:30:52AM#
```